# how to ignore two seconds difference when comparing two new Date()

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to compare two Date strings, i am getting slightly two seconds difference , can any one help how to ignore if two seconds difference ,

`const time1 : Fri Aug 18 2023 23:47:26 GMT+0530`

`const time1 : Fri Aug 18 2023 23:47:28 GMT+0530`

Comment: Subtract one from the other and test the absolute value of the difference.

Comment: `Math.abs(d1 - d2) > 2000` where `d1` and `d2` are Date Objects or ms time